# angular2 RC1 routing - get current outlet's component

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

i would like to get a hold of the router's current component in my Component to set it up.
I tried @ViewChild, routerOnActivate(:RouteSegment) and Router itself.

ViewChild remains undefined, segment's outlet property is just a string (__DEFAULT), and Router's #urlTree and #routeTree aren't providing it too.

Is there a way in angular2 ?

Answer (score 0):

You can either create your custom `<router-outlet>` implementation that provides means to get a reference to the added component but usually if you want to communicate with a routed component you do it using a shared service.

For more details see https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html